# Navbar binding not updating after login

Tags: angular

I am a bit new to angular2 and i understand all the basics but i have an issue about the binding of a component via a service which i do not understand. I would really like to understand what i am doing wrong in this case instead of just having a basic answer what needs to be changed.

I have an app.component.ts that handles my routing of the application and triggers my login component

```
# app.component.ts
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {LoginComponent} from "./authentication/login.component";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {NavbarComponent} from "./navbar/navbar.component";
import {User} from "./authentication/user.model";
import {AuthService} from "./authentication/auth.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        NavbarComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    precompile: [
        AppComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public user:User;

    constructor(private authService:AuthService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = this.authService.getUser();
        console.log("Application initialized ...");
    }
}
```

Since this class is for the main routing and login is mandatory it would be wise in my opinion to put the user object over there as a public property so i can reach it from everywhere easily. The login (which is forwarded via an auth.guard) is handled with below Component and auth service:

```
# login.component.ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {User} from "./user.model";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'authentication',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router:Router, private authService:AuthService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    login(event, username, password) {
        this.authService.login(username, password);
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
}
```

And the service:

```
# auth.service.ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from "./user.model";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    public user:User;

    login(username:string, password:string) {
        this.user = new User();
        this.user.id = 1;
        this.user.username = 'dummy username';
        this.user.email = 'foo@bar.com';
        this.user.name = 'My dummy testname';
        this.user.token = 'randomtokenverherefromwebserviceandstuff';
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }

    getUser() {
        this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

All this is working fine for my feeling atleast. The login is triggered well and after login the user is redirected to a generic component which is parsed in the router-outlet and that is going fine. The template for this is available in the `app.component.html` and looks like this:

```
# app.component.html
<app-navbar [user]="user"></app-navbar>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The problem over here is that after login the navbar user is empty and is not displayed at all. Nevertheless the navbar user is available once the page is refreshed where it gets the user from the local storage. Therefor i guess it has something to do with binding and it is not refreshing since it will retrieve it onInit i assume? Here is the code of the navbar itself:

```
# navbar.component.ts
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "../authentication/user.model";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from "../authentication/auth.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app-navbar",
    templateUrl: "./navbar.component.html",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavbarComponent {

    @Input() user:User;

    constructor(public router:Router, private authService:AuthService) {
    }

    logout() {
        this.authService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
}
```

I hope that someone could tell me what i am doing wrong or maybe even tell me that what im doing is the correct thing like this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try adding this edit

```
providers:[AuthService],
```

**edit**

also here is the git for the Auth0 configurations https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs2-systemjs-sample

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but where do you want me to add this? Since it is loaded in my main.ts at this point. (dont know if this is correct or maybe should be in app.component.ts though)

Comment: both your app component and nav bar component.

Comment: That is not doing the trick. I just checked your link and there is some usefull information to refactor but im still curious why this is not working as expected in my setup.

Comment: :\ sorry, thats all I can tell thats obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used `bi-directional communication` [from angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) for that. I put text from this topic below.

### Parent and children communicate via a service

A parent component and its children share a service whose interface enables bi-directional communication within the family.

The scope of the service instance is the parent component and its children. Components outside this component subtree have no access to the service or their communications.

This `MissionService` connects the `MissionControlComponent` to multiple `AstronautComponent` children.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MissionService {
  // Observable string sources
  private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();

  // Observable string streams
  missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
  }
  confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
    this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
  }
}
```

The `MissionControlComponent` both provides the instance of the service that it shares with its children (through the `providers` metadata array) and injects that instance into itself through its constructor:

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';
import { MissionService }     from './mission.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'mission-control',
  template: `
    <h2>Mission Control</h2>
    <button (click)="announce()">Announce mission</button>
    <my-astronaut *ngFor="let astronaut of astronauts"
      [astronaut]="astronaut">
    </my-astronaut>
    <h3>History</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let event of history">{{event}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers: [MissionService]
})
export class MissionControlComponent {
  astronauts = ['Lovell', 'Swigert', 'Haise'];
  history: string[] = [];
  missions = ['Fly to the moon!',
              'Fly to mars!',
              'Fly to Vegas!'];
  nextMission = 0;
  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    missionService.missionConfirmed$.subscribe(
      astronaut => {
        this.history.push(`${astronaut} confirmed the mission`);
      });
  }
  announce() {
    let mission = this.missions[this.nextMission++];
    this.missionService.announceMission(mission);
    this.history.push(`Mission "${mission}" announced`);
    if (this.nextMission >= this.missions.length) { this.nextMission = 0; }
  }
}
```

The `AstronautComponent` also injects the service in its constructor. Each `AstronautComponent` is a child of the `MissionControlComponent` and therefore receives its parent's service instance:

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MissionService } from './mission.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-astronaut',
  template: `
    <p>
      {{astronaut}}: <strong>{{mission}}</strong>
      <button
        (click)="confirm()"
        [disabled]="!announced || confirmed">
        Confirm
      </button>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AstronautComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input() astronaut: string;
  mission = '<no mission announced>';
  confirmed = false;
  announced = false;
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    this.subscription = missionService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
      mission => {
        this.mission = mission;
        this.announced = true;
        this.confirmed = false;
    });
  }
  confirm() {
    this.confirmed = true;
    this.missionService.confirmMission(this.astronaut);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

> Notice that we capture the `subscription` and unsubscribe when the
>   `AstronautComponent` is destroyed. This is a memory-leak guard step.
>   There is no actual risk in this app because the lifetime of a
>   `AstronautComponent` is the same as the lifetime of the app itself. That
>   would not always be true in a more complex application.
>
> We do not add this guard to the `MissionControlComponent` because, as
>   the parent, it controls the lifetime of the `MissionService`.

The *History* log demonstrates that messages travel in both directions between the parent `MissionControlComponent` and the `AstronautComponent` children, facilitated by the service:

[image]

### Test it

Tests click buttons of both the parent `MissionControlComponent` and the `AstronautComponent` children and verify that the *History* meets expectations:

```
// ...
it('should announce a mission', function () {
  let missionControl = element(by.tagName('mission-control'));
  let announceButton = missionControl.all(by.tagName('button')).get(0);
  announceButton.click().then(function () {
    let history = missionControl.all(by.tagName('li'));
    expect(history.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(history.get(0).getText()).toMatch(/Mission.* announced/);
  });
});
it('should confirm the mission by Lovell', function () {
  testConfirmMission(1, 2, 'Lovell');
});
it('should confirm the mission by Haise', function () {
  testConfirmMission(3, 3, 'Haise');
});
it('should confirm the mission by Swigert', function () {
  testConfirmMission(2, 4, 'Swigert');
});
function testConfirmMission(buttonIndex: number, expectedLogCount: number, astronaut: string) {
  let _confirmedLog = ' confirmed the mission';
  let missionControl = element(by.tagName('mission-control'));
  let confirmButton = missionControl.all(by.tagName('button')).get(buttonIndex);
  confirmButton.click().then(function () {
    let history = missionControl.all(by.tagName('li'));
    expect(history.count()).toBe(expectedLogCount);
    expect(history.get(expectedLogCount - 1).getText()).toBe(astronaut + _confirmedLog);
  });
}
// ...
```

### However I am a new in angular 2 too and I would like to hear the opinion of more experienced developers.